# How can I create MetadataReferences in Roslyn using the dependencies from a project.json file?

Tags: c#, roslyn, dnx

So in the new DNX world, they NuGet'ted all the things. I am writing DNX projects and I want to use Roslyn to analyze them. I expect to load the project.json file, determine the pattern of .cs files to include and then read the "references" needed to form the MetadataReferences needed by the compilation.

The problem I am running into is that project.json file refers to NuGet-style dependencies (which may even refer to projects elsewhere on the machine), but Roslyn only accepts exact references to the dependent assemblies' bits (file path, stream, etc.).

How would I interrogate the project.json file and end up with a list of MetadataReferences for the Roslyn analysis?

Comment: For now, there's no good (or easy) answer for this. Yes, I know this sucks and there's work going on that will eventually fix this, but until then, sorry. :-(

Comment: Thanks for replying even though the answer seems disappointing. And don't apologize; I understand I am just paying the price for living on the bleeding edge. You guys are doing amazing work and I and my team appreciate it greatly.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: Hi Jason. I have been asked to revisit this for our project. I may have to leave good (and easy) on the floor and do it some other way. Could you point me to the first thread I should pull if I insisted on doing this?

Comment: So we have something coming down the pipe very soon now

Comment: Super! Is it available in the vnext nuget feed? Usable by the end of the month?

Comment: Although no promises, hopefully we'll have something then.

Comment: So an update here: the [code is now public](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Workspaces/ProjectJsonWorkspace.cs) but I'm not sure if we have a NuGet package out yet that contains this binary. Worst case, you can sync and build it yourself but that kinda sucks.

Comment: "kinda sucks" beats "just can't do it". Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current "best answer" we have as of this writing is there is an implementation in the [.NET CLI](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Workspaces/ProjectJsonWorkspace.cs) repository. You can get NuGet packages from our nightly CLI feed of `https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-cli/`, but there is zero promise that these builds actually work at all. Make sure you check "prerelease" since everything there is prerelease.